# How can I select every cell in an ipython notebook?

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

This would be useful because I often want to use the builtin "Find and Replace" tool on every cell in the notebook, and this tool only works on *selected* cells.

To be clear, I want to select the cells in "command mode" -- I'm not talking about highlighting all the text. On my laptop, <kbd>Cmd+A</kbd> just highlights all the text.

Maybe some random plugin can do the trick?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can get the "Find and Replace" tool to work on every cell at once just by clicking on the "Replace in selected cells" toggle. It should be just to the left of the "find" box:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it! Use shift button to select multiple cells.
Note: you should click on the area left to entry field. Dont work with ctrl.

[image: 1]